# "This is the first time I've seen a person who have become..."

Tags: tense, present-perfect, subject-verb-agreement

Let's say you have never seen a woman who have become prettier compared to her previous look before she got pregnant. And you say:

> This is the first time **I've** seen a woman who **have become** so hot after she gets pregnant.(possibly a run-on sentence)

Is my sentence construction grammatical without any unclear thought when read.

Disclamer: The register is informal. The sentence constructed is only for the query.

Comment: one woman=has, singular verb.

Comment: John Arvin, you know we routinely close questions that ask for simple *correction*.  Could you add more detail to this one so it's clear why you wrote it this way and why you think it might (or might not) be correct?

Comment: Imho the cited text would be *extremely* unlikely coming from a native speaker, even after correcting ***who have*** to ***who has***, since those two words are completely unnecessary to the sense intended. Just say *This is the first time I've seen a woman become so hot after she gets pregnant*.

Comment: For a structurally similar example illustrating the same "unnecessarily complex tense" usage, compare [*I've never seen anyone **who has asked** so many questions before*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22anyone+who+has+asked+so+many%22) (no matches in Google Books) with [*I've never seen anyone **ask** so many questions before*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22anyone+ask+so+many%22) (29 hits). The first version is "grammatically valid", but in practice people usually avoid such pointlessly convoluted verb forms where they add nothing to the meaning.

Comment: I would never say something like that to any woman. It's creepy.

Comment: @Andrew, Yeah I get it, but I posted this type because I doubt that this is going to be a run-on sentence again with an involvement of different tenses(present perfect, then present tense at the end, while I am not sure if I should use ''got'' instead of ''gets'') so as an ESL, the sentence is short but there so many rules applied there.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, got it totally, cheers!

Comment: @MichaelHarvey, I know what you are saying, thx for the behavioural modification.

Comment: I realise you might specifically want to emphasise the [extended?] "process" [because being pregnant has a “rejuvenating effect” on women,](https://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/health/news/11526145/Pregnancy-really-does-make-women-bloom.html) but personally I'd probably leave all that as just "contextually implicit", and say something far simpler with effectively the same meaning: *I've never seen a pregnant woman **look/looking** so hot*. Where continuous implies *all the time* (while pregant), but infinitive ***look*** only really refers to how hot she is *right now* (as currently dressed, say).

Comment: @JohnArvin  Just include that explanation in the question, and I think you're good.  :)

Comment: @MichaelHarvey  Sure, but far less subtle statements are routine in contemporary music.  For better or worse, the language is what it is.

Comment: Language does not exist in a vacuum. It is used by people who have agency and choose what to say and write. there is a great deal said or sung in contemporary music that is deplorable. In rap, for example. –

Comment: @MichaelHarvey It is arrogant to decide what words are offensive to other people without reference to social context. Whether you view as a creep a husband who says to his wife **I think you look even hotter now that you are pregnant** is supremely irrelevant to me: what is important is how the wife perceives its intent. Moreover, your opinions about what words are offensive *per se* has nothing to do with question asked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not correct. The way you have bolded things, it appears that you think "have become" must agree with the main sentence's subject, "I"; but really it must agree with the subject of that particular phrase, which is "a woman".  So it requires the third-person singular "has become".

Answer (score 3):

Close. It should be "a woman who HAS become". "Woman" is singular, so it calls for a singular verb. "Has" is singular, "have" is plural.

An example with the plural would be, "I've seen many women who have become hotter after they got pregnant."

Comment: More precisely, *has* is **third person singular** present, and *have* is otherwise used for the present tense.  *Have* is not specifically plural; we say *I have*, for example.

Comment: Yes, good point. "has" is third person singular. First person singular and plural, second person singular and plulral, and third person plural all use "have".